# Google Apps Script HTTP Request and Host parameter

Tags: google-apps-script, http-headers, urlfetch

I'd like to make a HTTP GET request within a Google Apps Script.
I need the `Host` parameter inside the request header to be set:

```
function test() {
  var headers = {
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'host': 'myDomain.com'
  }
  var options = {
    'method' : 'get',
    'headers': headers
 };
 UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://my/api/endpoint', options);
```

However, adding the Host parameter inside the request parameters results in the following error: "Incorrect attribute Header:Host"

Exact same request perfectly works with Postman... Any insight on this?

Comment: If my answer was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

How about this modification? If you want to use `contentType` at `UrlFetchApp`, please put it to `options`. If you want to use it in the header, please use `Content-Type` as a key.

#### Pattern 1

```
var headers = {
  'Host': 'myDomain.com'
}
var options = {
  'method' : 'get',
  'headers': headers,
  'contentType': 'application/json'
};
```

#### Pattern 2

```
var headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Host': 'myDomain.com'
}
var options = {
  'method' : 'get',
  'headers': headers
};
```

#### Reference :

- [UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object))

If this didn't work, I'm sorry. At that time, can you show us the specification of API or samples?